# why use Google V8

Tags: v8

I don't get it. I'm a C/C++ programmer, what's the possible use of V8 for me? There are few examples and tutorials out there, and they all lack substance - I don't want to use another library to just add a couple of numbers or print something in a console window.
My question is: is there a real use for this technology, and if yes, then would be the scenario?
Also, can I do any part of GUI this way?

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Unless you are building a web browser you probably won't need it.

Answer (score 5):

["V8 is Google's open source JavaScript engine"](http://code.google.com/p/v8/)

So the whole point is ability to write code in JavaScript, and run it quite fast (for an interpreted dynamic language). Google Chrome, which is written in C++, uses it for internal scripting — not only for regular web page scripting, but also for extension code. Let's consider this as a 'real use'.

So, if your app needs scripting, V8 may be good for you (JS is not a perfect language, but stil quite decent). As for GUI, you'll need to bind your GUI components with JS first, there's no built-in UI components (as Tk in TCL).

Comment: The reason I even ask this question is that I really like JS, I'd love to use it in my code. But how (I mean what would justify that)? Also, any place I could learn how to bind GUI with JS? Thanks.

Comment: >>>>>uses it for internal scripting — not only for regular web page scripting, but also for extension code. Let's consider this as a 'real use'.

Comment: This is exactly the type of general information I find out there - doesn't mean anything concrete. I just want somebody to get through my stupidity and tell me a real scenario when anybody would use this in their C++ code.

Comment: A fancy config file could be written in JS :)

Answer (score 5):

One *real* use of v8 is node.js. I hope that is good enough

Comment: I think that's a good answer to the actual question. However, I think what he wanted to know is why use nodejs.

Answer (score 1):

Google V8 is a JavaScript engine.

I don't really think it is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

V8 is a JavaScript engine. The most common use for it is to allow users of your software to write scripts in simpler language than that your software was written with (C++ in your case).

It´s the same approach of Matlab, AutoCad, Microsoft Office, and etc.

If you write any kind of commercial application, you can expose some APIs and allow other developer to create addons for your applications without require them to know C/C++.

Answer (score 0):

How about this for **real use**: You can use javascript as a debugging or testing tool - add a javascript console to your app and bind the commands of your GUI application to javascript functions, and you'll be able to test your UI application using javascript scripts. This way you'll reduce the amount of manual testing needed - manual testing would only have to verify that a correct command was excutes as a result of user action.

You can do GUI in javascript the same way that *Qt* is being used in *Python* and other scripting languages (see PyQt, and QtRuby, PerlQt, etc.). For how to create bindings for V8 you may want to [check out this](http://code.google.com/apis/v8/embed.html)

Comment: That's what I do. I embeded it in a trading system, and people now use it to do regression tests, bench marking and what not. Javascript is very easy to write compared to C++. And JS and C++ can communicate and excahge data if you add API.